# I can't access my .env variables!! nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

Server is running on PORT: undefined in undefined mode.
MongoDB database connected with HOST: localhost

---

used to get Server is running on PORT: 4000 in development mode. and suddenly it's undefined for both and every variable in my .env, like cloudinary .. stripe ...

Comment: Can you please add some more descriptions to your problem, like some code what you are using?

Comment: I'll just shamelessly promote [wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config) as a replacement for your configuration needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this snippet before starting mongoDB to see what's getting to your node process env variables:

```js
console.log(process.env)
```

Also note that you can pass inline environment variables to node process like this:

```bash
PORT=4000 node ./my-script.js
```

To automatically load `.env` files, you might be using this package: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv so be sure that you have all packages installed (`npm install` or `yarn install`, depending on what you are using).

Comment: it works !! but only with npm start /// with nodemon I still get undefined for the env variables. (logged them to the console and I got undefined) I think the trouble with nodemon here

Answer (score 3):

One of the first things you should pay attention to is the file path. Check where your .env file is located in the project. If it is in the root of the project, there is no need to do anything. Otherwise, you must specify the path to the .env file.